# Cómo abrir una solución de Visual Studio 2015 a Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2010

Tengo un proyecto realizado en Visual Studio 2015 pero necesito abrirlo en Visual Studio 2010. Investigando, se tendría que abrir el archivo de la solución (*.sln) y cambiar la siguiente linea:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00

a

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

Y con eso solucionaría mi problema, el asunto es que no quiere hacer el cambio.

¿Porqué? ¿No se puede hacer esto con la versión 2015??

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no quiere hacer el cambio? ¿Quién no quiere hacer el cambio? Para cambiarlo simplemente tienes que abrir el archivo con un editor de texto (con el mismo Bloc de Notas por ejemplo) y cambiar la línea

Comment: Sigue marcando versión incompatible

Comment: @Alex Prueba edita .csproj TargetFrameworkVersion de " v4.5 "a" v4.0 ".

Comment: @Alex ¿Quieres convertir la solución de VS2015 a VS2010 o solo un proyecto?. Recuerda que una solución contiene varios proyectos. Asimismo, el título de tu pregunta no va acorde a tu pregunta, no se puede convertir VS2015 a VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin pude abrirlo.

Lo que hice fue en el archivo .csproj

puse esta linea asi:
v4.0

Agregue esta linea:
Client

Y en el archivo .sln puse la linea asi:
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00

Comment: y donde estan todas las otras lineas que mencionas? puedes poder la ruta?